# D3: Label layout on scatterplots

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scatter-plot, d3fc

I'm trying to do something about overlapping labels on the scatterplots like the one in the picture.

I'm using [d3fc](https://github.com/d3fc/d3fc-label-layout) and it does really good job positioning the labels, however, it's slow even with the small number of points (>100) but the actual requirement is usually >1000 points. It takes long to build the chart initially and zooming/padding is almost impossible.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong with d3fc? If not, are there any other stable approaches for automatic label layout available?

I'm using the greedy strategy:

> The greedy strategy is a very fast way of reducing label overlap. It
>   adds each label in sequence, selecting the position where the label
>   has the lowest overlap with already added rectangles and is inside the
>   container.
>
> `fc.layoutGreedy()`

Here is the jsFiddle with the simplified reproducible code (although it doesn't load d3fs lib) - https://jsfiddle.net/f5oxcyg7/

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a more complete and runnable example that exhibits your problem?

Comment: Hi @ColinE - I can't publish the actual code as it's embedded into a bigger Sencha ExtJS UI system, but I've tried to present the simplified version of the code to show how I use the d3fs. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: I think this is going to take a bit of work to sort out - the layout computation takes around 100ms, which is always going to make your zoom 'jumpy'. I've raised an issue here (https://github.com/d3fc/d3fc-label-layout/issues/24) and will try to find a decent solution.

Comment: thanks very much @ColinE. That's really great package! Perhaps you might edit your answer a bit so that people can cancel their downvotes... Sorry about that, and thanks again for great work and desire to help.

Comment: No problem - and I have a solution for you :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that the layout strategy is being re-evaluated every time the chart is rendered. Typically a ~100ms render time when first rendering a chart is not a problem, but if you need smooth pan / zoom, then this becomes a problem.

The solution I have come up with is to 'cache' the result of the layout, so that it is not re-evaluated while the chart is being zoomed. However, when the zoom operation finishes, the layout is re-evaluated to remove collisions.

First, the zoom events are handled to turn the cache behaviour on / off:

```
var returnCachedLayout = false;
var zoomBeh = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x)
    .y(y)
    .scaleExtent([0, 500])
    .on("zoomstart", function() {
      returnCachedLayout = true;
        zoom()
     })
    .on("zoom", zoom)
    .on("zoomend", function() {
      returnCachedLayout = false;
        zoom()
     })
```

Then the strategy is adapted to make use of the cache:

```
var strategyCache = function (strategy) {
  var cachedLayout;

  var cache = function(layout) {
    if (!returnCachedLayout) {
      cachedLayout = strategy(layout);
      // determine the offset applied by the layout
      for (var i = 0; i< layout.length; i++) {
        cachedLayout[i].dx = layout[i].x - cachedLayout[i].x;
        cachedLayout[i].dy = layout[i].y - cachedLayout[i].y;
      }
    } else {
      // update the location of each label, including the offset
      for (var i = 0; i< layout.length; i++) {
        cachedLayout[i].x = layout[i].x - cachedLayout[i].dx;
        cachedLayout[i].y = layout[i].y - cachedLayout[i].dy;
      }
    }
    return cachedLayout;
  };
  return cache;
};

// construct a strategy that uses the "greedy" algorithm for layout, wrapped
// by a strategy that removes overlapping rectangles.
var strategy = strategyCache(fc.layout.strategy.removeOverlaps(fc.layout.strategy.greedy()));
```

It's a little tricky because you cannot just re-render the labels from the cache because the zoom behaviour will have caused these points to move. This is why the offset is also stored so that it can be re-applied to the labels at the new location.

Anyhow, here's a complete example:

https://jsfiddle.net/qrpr0wre/

I'll look to make this a 'first class' feature of d3fc-label-layout soon.